# React Native Video Call Notification

Tags: react-native, android-notifications, agora.io, callkit, react-native-onesignal

I am using react-native-agora for video calling app, i have successfully implemented the video calling function in react-native app. Now I want to show the user notification with Answer and Declined button, i have read out that react-native-callkeep will be helpful, but as i go through the docs, i found that it requires unnecessary permissions.
I am using OneSignal to send notification, I just want the notification to keep vibrating/looping for some seconds untill the user decide to answer or decline the call.

Comment: were you able to resolve the situation and implement notifications for android and ios?

Answer (score 0):

To implement call notification, you need to integrate the **Agora RTC SDK**, the **Agora RTM SDK**, and platform-specific call APIs such as ConnectionService for Android, CallKit for iOS, and **CallKeep** for Flutter and **React Native**. The RTM SDK supports call notification only when the app is running. So, you also need to integrate platform-specific APIs to ensure that users can still receive call notifications when the app is on the background or the process is closed.

Agora officially supports provides [documentation](https://docs.agora.io/en/All/faq/call_invite_notification) to help you integrate CallKeep.

## Implementation

- **Step 1:** Integrate the RTC SDK and the RTM SDK
  Refer to the following articles to learn how to integrate the RTC SDK and the RTM SDK:

1. [RTC SDK quickstart](https://docs.agora.io/en/Interactive%20Broadcast/start_live_android?platform=Android)
2. [RTM SDK quickstart](https://docs.agora.io/en/Real-time-Messaging/messaging_android?platform=Android)

- **Step 2:** Use the RTM SDK to implement the basic functionalities of call invitation
  To implement call invitation for the RTM SDK, see [Call Invitation](https://docs.agora.io/en/Real-time-Messaging/rtm_invite_android?platform=Android).
- **Step 3:** Integrate platform-specific call APIs and implement call notification
  For the React Native platform, see [CallKeep official documentation](https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-callkeep).

I would recommend this as the safest bet.